# Error in scapy python Debian

Tags: debian, python

Good afternoon, I created a simple sniffer on Debian but I can't run it.

```
from scapy.all import *


counter = 0

def analysis(pkt):
   global counter
   print(counter, ":  Ethernet")
   print("Src:", pkt["Ether"].src)
   print("Dst:", pkt["Ether"].dst)
   print(pkt.sprintf("Type: %Ether.type%"))

   if pkt["Ether"].type == 2054:     #ARP
      print("###ARP###")
      if pkt["ARP"].op == 1:
          print("echo-request")
      elif pkt["ARP"].op == 2:
          print("echo-reply")

   elif pkt["Ether"].type == 2048:   #IPv4
      print("###IPv4###")
      print("Src:", pkt["IP"].src)
      print("Dst:", pkt["IP"].dst)
      print("TTL:", pkt["IP"].ttl)
      print("High level protocol: ", pkt.sprintf("%IP.proto%"))    #udp 17
      print("Data size:", pkt["IP"].len-20)
      if pkt["IP"].proto == 17:
          print("     ###UDP###")
          print("     Src port:", pkt["UDP"].sport)
          print("     Dst port:", pkt["UDP"].dport)
          print("     Data size:", pkt["UDP"].len - 8)

  counter += 1
  print("---------------------------------------------------")


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    ifaces = os.listdir('/sys/class/net/')
    sniff(iface=ifaces, prn=analysis)
```

An error occurs when running in Pycharm (tried on python3.7 and 3.9:

```
home/danya/Python-3.9.1/python /home/danya/PycharmProjects/main.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/danya/PycharmProjects/main.py", line 40, in <module>
  sniff(iface=ifaces, prn=analysis)
File "/home/danya/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1263, in sniff
  sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/danya/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1127, in _run
  sniff_sockets[L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, iface=iface,
File "/home/danya/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 486, in init
  self.ins = socket.socket(
File "/home/danya/Python-3.9.1/Lib/socket.py", line 232, in init
  _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

run with sudo privilege.

scaly needs sudo privilege to sniff traffic on an interface

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in Pycharm?

Comment: you can run pycharm as root . (security issues here). or you run it from the command line interface if it has. haven't used pycharm for a long while so I don't know if it has a terminal but.

Comment: or you could edit the pycharm python configuration file to include sudo. but this will also run for script you don't need superuser privilege for. the best choice is to run from the terminal.

Comment: when running sudo python3 * .py in the terminal it gives the same errors

Comment: solved a problem:
 iface should be a string, not a list